# Hidden input is messing up grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am using twitter bootstrap to style my admin panels, however this is very strange behavior. I've tested in Chrome 28 and Firefox and it messes up grid when I add a simple hidden input.

If you move hidden input into `div.span6` or remove it completely it will work as intended, but if it stays there the rows collapse and do not work properly. By properly I mean that they should be next to each other, not on top.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EZMvB/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form action="/admin/category/create" class="row-fluid" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="WAT" value="WAT" />
        <div class="span6">
            <label for="NameEnglish">Name (English)</label>
            <input class="input-block-level" name="NameEnglish" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <label for="NameEnglish">Name (English)</label>
            <input class="input-block-level" name="NameEnglish" type="text">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-large btn-primary pull-right">
    </form>
</div>
```

[image: Problem picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting class `row-fluid` in `<form>` tag in general is bad practice, because you always end up with one row, where as you could end up needing more then one row in your code.

Example here in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6EJL2/1/)

Code:

```
<form action="/admin/category/create"  method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="hidden" />
    <div class="row-fluid" >
         <div class="span6">
             <label for="NameEnglish">Name (English)</label>
             <input class="input-block-level" data-val="true" data-val-required="'Name English' should not be empty." id="NameEnglish" name="NameEnglish" type="text" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="span6">
             <label for="NameEnglish">Name (English)</label>
             <input class="input-block-level" id="NameEnglish" name="NameEnglish" type="text" value="">
         </div>
             <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-large btn-primary pull-right">
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: skmasq, do you know why a hidden field affects the layout in a `row-fluid`?

Comment: @sellmeadog even if it's default value is `display: none` the `input` element takes up some space very minimal in DOM, you can see if you minimize width % to 46 not 48, it will work properly. Why is that, I don't know.

Comment: skmasq, makes no sense. `display: none` should prevent it from being rendered at all and therefore not take up any space. I would understand if there was a `visibility: hidden` rule somewhere, but no display should mean no affect to layout.

Comment: @sellmeadog completely agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work as desired if you move the hidden field (http://jsfiddle.net/EZMvB/1/). Not sure why placement matters since the default style of `display: none` should prevent it from affecting layout?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form action="/admin/category/create" class="row-fluid" method="post">
        <div class="span6">
            <label for="NameEnglish">Name (English)</label>
            <input class="input-block-level" name="NameEnglish" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <label for="NameEnglish">Name (English)</label>
            <input class="input-block-level" name="NameEnglish" type="text">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-large btn-primary pull-right">
        <input type="hidden" name="WAT" value="WAT" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hidden fields represents anti-forgery token. Thanks, this solves the problem.

Comment: Glad it worked. And I was saying I don't know why the placement of the hidden field affects layout, not why you need to use one. Updated my answer to clarify.